# Get QPainter drawn text dimensions

Tags: qt, text, qpainter

I want to draw some text using `QPainter::drawText` command.

In order to set its position properly I need to know the dimension of drawn string in pixels.

Is there a way to know pixel dimension of the string? Possibly without drawing it before?

Comment: What kind of dimensions you need? Maybe you need QFontMetrics?

Comment: I need the bounding box of the string in pixels.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-2 ?

Comment: Thanks QFontMetrics is what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QFontMetrics` class has a method just for this purpose: `boundingRect()`.

From the Qt docs (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-2):

`Returns the bounding rectangle of the characters in the string specified by text.`

Note that the bounding rect **only** provides the width of drawn text, the `width()` function provides the width of trailing spaces as well. Also from the Qt docs:

`boundingRect() returns a rectangle describing the pixels this string will cover whereas width() returns the distance to where the next string should be drawn.`